# convert sql resultset to string, php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am have two php scripts, say "first.php" which calls another php, "second.php" script with a GET value.

The first.php calls the second.php by using GET method.

The GET method value is a string retrieved from the database .

first.php code

```
$someString = mysqli_query($connectionName,"SELECT someString from db where id=1";

/* Then the php redirects to ->" */

'mywebsite.com/PHP/second.php?data='.someString
```

second.php

```
if(isset($_GET['data']))
{
     $new_data = $_GET['data'];

}
```

My problem is that, the data in "someString" is in resultset format ,So I am getting a php error that the GET method needs a String value.

Is there any possible way to convert the sql resultset to string?

Comment: are you using <form action="mywebsite.com/PHP/second.php"> to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$someStringRes = mysqli_query($connectionName,"SELECT someString from db where id=1";

$row=mysqli_fetch_row($someStringRes);

$someString = $row[0];

/* Then the php redirects to ->" */

'mywebsite.com/PHP/second.php?data='.someString
```

Answer (score 0):

if php redirects means it will be simple

```
<?php
$res = mysqli_query($connectionName,"SELECT someString from db where id=1";
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$data=$row[0];
header('Location: mywebsite.com/PHP/second.php?data='.$data);
?>
```

OR
I assumed that you used form action to transfer datas: try this

```
<?php
$res = mysqli_query($connectionName,"SELECT someString from db where id=1";
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$data=$row[0];
?>
<form action='mywebsite.com/PHP/second.php'>
<input type="text" name="data" value="<?php echo $data;?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now the url pass like this mywebsite.com/PHP/second.php?data=//value. you can retrieve it

```
<?php
$data=$_GET[data];
?>
```